# Ruby Sinatra Upload Form params Disturbed

Tags: ruby, parameters, sinatra

Upon submitting a form in Sinatra, I'm coming up with the following error:

```
App 40327 output: 2018-06-28 02:59:17 - NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
App 40327 output:   /Library/WebServer/Documents/blammo/routes/publish.rb:87:in `block in <class:MyApp>'
```

The form is a file upload form, and a single text field.  Simple.  The file goes through, as does the text field.  They are both captured just fine.

I submit the `params` to a method,  which is ultimately responsible for generating the error on the following line down the page:

```
fname = params[:s_single_file_upload][:filename]
```

The method in question returns fine with a boolean.  I've rewritten it a couple of ways and flushed out anything that might trip something I'm
unfamiliar with.

So the `params` is messed up if this method mentioned above is being called.  So fname can't be assigned.  I expect the `params` to be intact 
at this point in the code.  Is there any destruction if the `params` are perused before this point?  In another language, I've seen `params` destroyed
in one way or another for some reason, but I'm not sure about `Ruby`.

I'm not finding any nil:NilClass, but that's exactly what it's reporting.  Here's the trigger of this method:

```
result = Alpha::rf_alpha_sniff(params)
```

And the module::method:

```
module Alpha

  def self.rf_alpha_sniff(incoming)
    qualifiers = %w(alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot)
    incoming.delete('captures')
    incoming.delete('splat')            # take out Mustermann's 'captures' and 'splat'
    incoming.delete('s_single_file_upload')         # non-perusal 'single_file_upload'    
    incoming.values.each do |item|
      item = item.gsub(" ","_")
      Dev::hq_log("item: #{ qualifiers.include?(item.downcase) }")
      return true if qualifiers.include?(item.downcase)
    end
    return false
  end

end
```

So the page progresses fine without this method.  When the method is induced any way, the `params` seem to get screwed up, so the file is pretty much
gone.

How is this method interfering with the `params` so that it's unavailable later on down the script?  I'm expecting it to be fully available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, using `incoming.delete` was deleting items from the `params` hash, as it was a reference to the original, instead of using a copy.

So, I have to copy the `params` by using `params.dup` (duplicate) so they are not the same object.

Having a view of the `params` hash post-testing-method, showed me that objects were indeed deleted.  Another one solved.